# How to remove a local Git repo from TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I started messing around with Git today. I think I've done something wrong because when I installed TortoiseGit it looks like a lot of folders in my C and F (second partition) have a green tick next to them (meaning the file is commited? I think?). What can I do to remove these ticks. Is there a way to NOT delete the actual files/folders but just a file or two that tells Windows to add a green tick to the icon? I'm a bit scared working with stuff like that on my C:. **In other words - is there a way to undo the "init" action?! Please see image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKa1o.png**

I'm new to Git so sorry for non professional vocab in this question. Thanks.

Comment: I searched this forum but nothing helped!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't know about TortoiseGit but the `git init` command simply creates a (hidden) `.git` directory in the root of the repository and fills it with some needed files. So to undo an init all you need to do is to delete this `.git` directory. Note that some files in this directory can be write protected, so a warning dialog can appear. Please also note that all commits you have made in this repository will be lost (which should be no problem in your case).

However I don't know if this works or is enough when using TortoiseGit…

Comment: I believe having a sea creature o it for you makes no difference here.

Comment: **Doesn't matter - I found out how to see hidden files. I deleted couple of .git folders however the green ticks don't go away. Why?**

Comment: @RafalChmiel Maybe you have to tell TortoiseGit to refresh (or restart your computer).

Comment: Woho! Thanks, it worked (yet again)! Thank you very much man - really helpful!

Comment: I do confirm that you simply have to delete the .git folder. The TortoiseGit icon adornments in the Windows file explorers remains until next reboot (at least under Windows XP) !

Answer (score 2):

Remove the .git folder in your repository.

Answer (score 1):

open git bash then execute below command

`$ rm -rf .git`

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows -git now locks folder